How to debug a running Docker service in PyCharm?
I have a Docker container service I'd like to place breakpoints and debug while the service is running. Right now, it looks like I can only Run the service and no debug option:

Is there a way to run the service and debug it?
This is a python service which I send a json payload and it returns success or not.
If I'm testing a specific python file, I can debug it while running inside a container. But if I run the specific python file, then I can't send a payload via postman to see a return message. Hope this makes sense, I'm sort of new at this.

I tend to treat this case like other production-like setups: set up a purely local development environment (with no container infrastructure at all), reproduce the issue there, and debug that.

You need to configure a remote interpreter. It is described in Pycharm documentation:

Do one of the following:

Click the Python Interpreter selector and choose Add New Interpreter.
Press Ctrl+Alt+S  to open Settings and go to Project:     | Python Interpreter. Click the Add Interpreter link next to
the list    of the available interpreters.
Click the Python Interpreter selector and choose Interpreter    Settings. Click the Add Interpreter link next to the list of the
available interpreters.


Select On Docker.

Select an existing Docker configuration in the Docker server dropdown.

Wait for PyCharm to connect to the Docker daemon and complete the container introspection.

Select an interpreter to use in the Docker container.


There is also a how to run and debug a django app running in docker using Pycharm. It is a bit more visual than Pycharm documentation.
